# Loading text files with requires.js fails in Firefox: "AccessControlException"

Tags: javascript, firefox, requirejs

i am using requires.js 2.0. I have the following simplified use case:

my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-main="apptest.js" src="../_js/libs/require/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

And then in apptest.js:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'text': '../_js/libs/require/text'
    }
});

requirejs(
    ['text!boxes.html'],

    function (Boxes) {
        alert("done");
    }
);
```

Ok, so it doesn't really do much, but enough to make my point. Only in Firefox (14.0.1) i get an exception "uncaught exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission .\boxes.html read)".

So, require.js successfully loaded the text plugin, but fails loading my html file, which i want to use as a template later on. In Google Chrome and even IE9 it works just fine. I am on Windows 7.

I am running this on a local webserver, so no file://... requests here.

I have checked, if i have any special permissions set on the html file, but have not found anything suspicious.

Anyone have an idea?

**Update**: Running the test in Firefox 13.0.1 does actually work for me without errors. So could it be, that this is a bug, that has been introduced in firefox 14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem a minute ago. I've fixed it by doing the following in the main.js file (where you setup the config)

Before the

```
require.config({.....
```

add the following code:

```
Packages = undefined;
```

This should do the trick.

You should have something like this:

```
Packages = undefined;

require.config({
    baseUrl: theAppBaseUrl,
    paths: {
```

Basically the explanation is that it is trying to use Java to get the file instead of an ajax request (for whatever reason). This forces it to use an XHR object to fetch it.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, that works, so i mark it as an answer. Meanwhile, i got an answer from the require team on github as well. It seems to be an issue in the text plugin. switching the plugin back to version 2.0.1 also fixes the issue: https://github.com/requirejs/text/issues/13

Comment: Yeah - I assumed it was a bug. So the 2.0.1 works. Good to know. Thanks!

Comment: Update to this: I just encountered the same issue, and following the above link, found that this has been fixed in version 2.0.3 of the plugin, which has now been released: https://github.com/requirejs/text/blob/latest/text.js